# Why does the function levenshtein in PHP have a 255-character limit?

Tags: php, function, levenshtein-distance

Does anybody know why the function **[levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)** in PHP has a 255-character limit?

Comment: Interesting question. On first glance, the [commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/6b5c37a8c5d00e204dc80315615fb95ac22e8a49#diff-c9bca235d042c246b4a368797402d3c9) that introduced the limit doesn't say why.

Comment: Unless we get the original dev or team who first implemented this, I don't think we can ever find the answer, but if I had to guess I would say because it was failing performance requirements for larger strings.

Comment: `// fixed slow algorithm implementation by limiting input size, 255 is enough for everyone, riiiiight?` 

Comment: If I use levenshtein without database it allocate data inside a var. Php not limit var at 255bit. 
The [commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/6b5c37a8c5d00e204dc80315615fb95ac22e8a49#diff-c9bca235d042c246b4a368797402d3c9) say enforce lenght limit and catch out-ouf-memory conditions, so there is a limit in var in this implementation in C?

Comment: If you can read C, here's php's implementation of it: [ext/standard/levenshtein.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/b1f65fb25b2b054d98f2db4b30f20f8368740b5a/ext/standard/levenshtein.c#L25)

Comment: @FabianLauer the significant change that was made in that commit was the switch from normal C-style `malloc` (which debug mode PHP complains about memory leaks) to PHPs own `emalloc` . I'm guessing there's a limit to `emalloc` , though this is just speculation. The actual implementation goes a bit above my head

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this topic after 2022: this seems to not be an issue anymore. Tested this in php8.1 and it does not throw an error anymore. Cannot find it in the changelog, but it seems to be fixed. So, upgrade to php > 8.1 :D

Answer (score 3):

This is the PHP full implementation for the function. As you can see there are nested loop based on string characters length:

> ```
> function lev($s,$t) {
>   $m = strlen($s);
>   $n = strlen($t);
>
>   for($i=0;$i<=$m;$i++) $d[$i][0] = $i;
>   for($j=0;$j<=$n;$j++) $d[0][$j] = $j;
>
>   for($i=1;$i<=$m;$i++) {
>     for($j=1;$j<=$n;$j++) {
>       $c = ($s[$i-1] == $t[$j-1])?0:1;
>       $d[$i][$j] = min($d[$i-1][$j]+1,$d[$i][$j-1]+1,$d[$i-1][$j-1]+$c);
>     }
>   }
>
>   return $d[$m][$n];
> }
> ```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#PHP

the version for PHP named `levenshtein()` in PHP starting from version 4.0.1 to 255 chars length.

I think the limitation is introduced to maintain performance and duration in a most acceptable range.

If you need string comparison for lengths > 255, you could use the implementation above.

Comment: this is the PHP implementation  .., and obviosly .. is much more havier then the C implementation  .. you can choose .. the implemantion you prefer ..

Comment: I'm adding catch to use the native levenshtein unless a string is too long

Answer (score -3):

PHP's levenshtein() function can only handle up to 255 characters, which is not realistic for user input (only the first paragraph of this post has 285 characters). If you choose to use a custom function able to handle more than 255 characters, efficiency is an important issue.

I use this function, specific for this case, but much faster:

```
function ucase_percent ($str) {
    $str2 = strtolower ($str);

    $l = strlen ($str);
    $ucase = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        if ($str{$i} != $str2{$i}) {
            $ucase++;
        }
    }

    return $ucase / $l * 100.0;
}
```

Comment: The OP did not ask for an implementation without that limit, but why that limit is there