# Full text document similarity search

Tags: php, mysql, solr, levenshtein-distance, morelikethis

I have big database of articles and I'd like before adding new items to DB check if already similar items exist and if so - group them together, so that later I can easily display them as a group of similar items.

Currently we use very simple, but shockingly very precise and our needs fully satisfying PHP's `similar_text()` function. The problem is, that before we add an item to DB, we first need to pull X amount of items from DB to then loop through every single one in order to check whether our new item is at least **75% similar** to other items in order to group them together. This uses a lot of resources and time that we don't really have.

We use MySQL and Solr for all our queries. I've tried using MySQL *Full-Text Search*, Solr *More like this*. Compared to PHPs implementation, they are super fast and efficient, but I just can't get a robust percentage score which PHP `similar_text()` provides. It is crucial for our grouping to be accurate.

For example using this MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, body,  ROUND(((MATCH(body) AGAINST ('ARTICLE TEXT')) / scores.max_score) * 100) as relevance
FROM natural_text_test,
     (SELECT MAX(MATCH(body) AGAINST('ARTICLE TEXT')) as max_score FROM natural_text_test LIMIT 1) scores
HAVING relevance > 75
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

i get that article with 130 words is 85% similar with another article with 4700 words. And in comparison PHP's `similar_text()` returns only 3% similarity score which is well below our threshold and is correct in our case.

I've also looked into *Levenshtein distance* algorithm, but it seems that the same problem as with MySQL and Solr arises.

There has to be a better way to handle similarity checks, maybe I'm using the algorithms incorrectly?

Comment: *I've also looked into Levenshtein distance algorithm, but it seems that the same problem as with MySQL and Solr arises.* Did you test it, or did you just assume it? Levenshtein is much (much, much) closer to how similar_text works than to how MySQL fulltext search works. (It is even similarly slow.)

Comment: I've tried PHP's `levenshtein()` function. So it has only 255 char limit on text, which 95% of my articles exceed. I've tried implementing my own from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201329/8650000 but probably because it's written in PHP the performance is terrible. `Similar_text()` took 0.2 seconds while this levenshtein implementation took almost 20 seconds. But if it is actually very similar in how they work, i guess i'll invest more time into MySQL/levenshtein implementation.

Comment: Levenshtein is very CPU-intensive.  And it only check for a few flavors of "similarity".  What is your goal?  Recognize customized spam?  Redundant ads?  Something else?

Comment: Do you care about the "order" of the tokens (words/letters) in each string?  Some algorithms give higher relevance when the two texts are in the same order.  I would expect FULLTEXT to give high similarity for a string of words and that string in reverse order.  But the others might give very little similarity.  Which do you want?

Comment: If `similiar_text` is the comparison you want, you might want to look into how you can reduce the number of documents you have to pull instead of thinking about similarity in percent - fulltext search talk about (and is optimized for) relevancy generally, and not similarity. I'd suggest looking at algorithms and libraries for plagiarism detection instead; that seems to be closer to what you're actually looking for. One of the techniques used are ngram search, which you can get with Solr etc; but exactly how useful it is would depend on your input structure (a long ngram as a search tool?)

Comment: @RickJames So my exact problem is: some new sites basically repost same articles. They some times change couple words or add some paragraphs. I need to group such articles. We gave PHPs `similar_text()` a shot and it worked surprisingly well. I don't really care about how _relevant_ the articles are, just how close to being identical they are. And basically if they have 75% or more of the same text, then I need to group them. So maybe @MatsLindh is right and I need to look into plagiarism detection.

Comment: @RickJames about order. I think it should matter. If two articles are identical but one text is scrambled then they should be very different. I need to find near duplicates. If articles are about same subject, they might be written similarly, but they shouldn't grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the Comments, I might propose this...

It seems that 75%-similar documents would have a lot of the same sentences in the same order.

1. Break the doc into sentences
2. Take a crude hash of each sentence, map it to a visible ascii character.  This gives you a string that is, perhaps, 1/100th the size of the original doc.
3. Store that with the doc.
4. When searching, use levenshtein() on this string to find 'similar' documents.

Sure, hashing is imperfect, etc.  But this is fast.  And you could apply some other technique to double-check the few docs that are close.

For a hash, I might do

```
$md5 = md5($sentence);
$x = somehow get 6 bits out of that hex string
$hash = chr(ord('0' + $x));
```